# ¿Cómo hago que un fondo cambie de imágenes cada 5 segundos con html y javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estoy intentando poner un fondo de imágenes que vayan cambiando para una maqueta de una página web.
En este caso no se por dónde empezar el código.
Les agradecería mucho la ayuda .

Comment: Tu pregunta se vuelve demasiado amplia, intenta especificar un poco mas tu pregunta y agregar algo que hubieras intentado. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no necesariamente necesitas javascript, mira aquí te dejo un ejemplo de cómo hacerlo solo con css http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CSS3FullscreenSlideshow/

Answer (score 1):

Podrias usar el `setInterval` de javascript para ir iterando las imagenes

```js
var index = 0;

    var listaimg = ["http://i.imgur.com/1eHivZy.png", "http://images.neopets.com/template_images/acarabackground.gif", "http://i.imgur.com/cji4OHQ.jpg", "https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGlzr.png"];

$(function() {
  
    setInterval(changeImage, 2000);
  
});

function changeImage() {
  
 
   $('body').css("background-image", 'url(' + listaimg[index] + ')');
                  
   index++;
                  
   if(index == 4)
      index = 0;
    
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
<style>
body  {
    background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGlzr.png");
    background-color: #cccccc;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Hello World!</h1>

</body>
</html>
```